# Getting deployment error for ColdFusion 8 RDS on JBoss. How to fix this?

Tags: jboss, coldfusion

I have deployed ColdFusion 8 on JBoss 5.1.0. During the CF installation only two WARs have been created instead of one EAR, no porblem.

I am able to start the CF admin gui but i get the following error when the rds.war should be deployed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.SecurityException: Seed must be between 20 and 64 bytes. Only 8 bytes supplied.

        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:313)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:190)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:231)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:88)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:120)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.invokeOperation(AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:482)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/rds.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.SecurityException: Seed must be between 20 and 64 bytes. Only 8 bytes supplied.

        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:993)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:939)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:873)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.start(AbstractDeployHandler.java:265)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.invoke(AbstractDeployHandler.java:177)
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:305)
        ... 15 more
```

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line to your arguments for the JVM

```
-Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true
```

Thank you, Dave Shuck -> http://daveshuck.instantspot.com/blog/2009/05/08/Solving-javalangSecurityException-Seed-must-be-between-20-and-64-bytes-Only-8-bytes-supplied